# Filter Object by key and value

Tags: javascript, node.js

Is there anyway to filter an object conditionally checking both the key and value? What I am trying to do is check if the key equals a string and check whether or not the value is empty.

I am trying to detect whether or not Teaching Hospital has an empty value, but Teaching Hospital Tax ID does not and vice-versa. If Teaching Hospital Name has a value, but Teaching Hospital Tax ID does not, the returned result should be: {Teaching Hospital Tax ID: ""}.

**Object**

```
{
  'Manufacturer Name': 'Ascendis',
  'HCP First Name': 'John',
  'HCP Middle Name': '',
  'HCP Last Name': '',
  'HCP NPI': 2442,
  'HCP Credentials': '',
  'HCP State License Number': '',
  'HCP State of Licensure': '',
  'HCP Specialty': '',
  'Teaching Hospital Name': 'Trinity',
  'Teaching Hospital Tax ID': '',
  'Address 1': '',
  'Address 2': '',
  'Postal Code': '',
  'Spend Date': '',
  'Spend Currency': '',
  'Spend Amount': '',
  'Form of Payment': '',
  'Nature of Payment': '',
  'Home System Identifier': '',
  'Product Name': '',
  'Travel City': '',
  'Travel State': '',
  'Travel Country': ''
}
```

**Code**

```
Object.entries(item)
          .filter(([key, value]) => (key === "Teaching Hospital Name" && value != "") && (key === "Teaching Hospital Tax ID" && value === ""))
```

Comment: What is the expected result? Can you provide an example of the object?

Comment: Normally it's `.filter((item, index) => {})`

Comment: Your filter condition can never become true because you have `key === 'foo' && key === 'bar'`

Comment: Are you trying to filter the object properties, or an array of objects?

Comment: I edited my post and included thee object. The logic behind what I am trying to accomplish is to filter the object to check if certain conditions are met. Such as flagging the user if the key (Teaching Hospital) has a value but key (Teaching Hospital Tax ID) is empty.

Comment: @Sharif you missing to return `Object.fromEntries`. see my answer for more details

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lets analyse what we got and what we want.

- We have a model `obj`.
- We want pick specific keys and run specific check against picked keys/values
- The check returns object with those keys which values are empty string
- Additionally the check will ignore the results if all values are empty

We could write above as

```
1. if(allValues has an empty string) return false // ignore results
2. if(allValues has NOT an empty string) return false // ignore 3. results
3. return object with those keys where value is empty string
```

which in JS would looks like

```js
// your model
const obj = {}
// your group of keys you want to pick from object
const group = [];
// picked [[key,value]] defined by your group
const entries = Object.entries(obj).filter(([key]) => group.includes(key));
// filter out those which are empty
const emptyEntries = entries.filter(([key, value]) => value === ""); 
// 1. step - to check if all values are empty we can check lengths
if(entries.length === emptyEntries.length) return false;
// 2. step - just check if filtered length is 0
if(emptyEntries.length === 0) return false
// 3. step - convert your emptyEntries to object
return Object.fromEntries(emptyEntries);
```

Lets see if below code works for you

```js
const obj = {
  'Manufacturer Name': 'Ascendis',
  'HCP First Name': 'John',
  'HCP Middle Name': '',
  'HCP Last Name': '',
  'HCP NPI': 2442,
  'HCP Credentials': '',
  'HCP State License Number': '',
  'HCP State of Licensure': '',
  'HCP Specialty': '',
  'Teaching Hospital Name': 'Trinity',
  'Teaching Hospital Tax ID': '',
  'Address 1': '',
  'Address 2': '',
  'Postal Code': '',
  'Spend Date': '',
  'Spend Currency': '',
  'Spend Amount': '',
  'Form of Payment': '',
  'Nature of Payment': '',
  'Home System Identifier': '',
  'Product Name': '',
  'Travel City': '',
  'Travel State': 'nonempty',
  'Travel Country': ''
}
function check(obj, groupArr) {
  const group = new Set(groupArr);
  const vals = Object.entries(obj).filter(([key, value]) => group.has(key) && value === "");
  if(vals.length === group.size || vals.length === 0) return false;
  return Object.fromEntries(vals);
}
console.log(check(obj, ["Travel City", "Travel State", "Travel Country"]));
/* results
{
   "Travel City": "",
   "Travel Country": ""
}
*/
```

Comment: I am trying to filter for those records that do not pass. I am trying to detect whether or not Teaching Hospital has an empty value, but Teaching Hospital Tax ID does not and vice-versa. If Teaching Hospital Name has a value, but Teaching Hospital Tax ID does not, the returned result should be: {Teaching Hospital Tax ID: ""}

Comment: so is it only for Teaching Hospital Name and Teaching Hospital Tax ID?

Comment: No there are additional parameters:  Stackoverflow will not allow me to format it via a comment so I hope you can decipher what I'm trying to accomplish.

Comment: || key ["Teaching Hospital Name"] != "" && item["Teaching Hospital Tax ID"] === ""
            || key["Teaching Hospital Tax ID"] != "" && item["Teaching Hospital Name"] === ""

            || key["Travel City"] != "" && key["Travel State"] === "" && key["Travel Country"] === ""
            || key["Travel City"] === "" && key["Travel State"] != "" && key["Travel Country"] === ""
            || key["Travel City"] === "" && key["Travel State"] === "" && key["Travel Country"] != ""

            || key["Travel City"] != "" && key["Travel State"] != "" && key["Travel Country"] === ""

Comment: || key["Travel City"] != "" && key["Travel State"] === "" && key["Travel Country"] != ""
            || key["Travel City"] === "" && key["Travel State"] != "" && key["Travel Country"] != ""

Comment: this is quite specific. But let me think

Comment: I have the rest of my code working so you don't have to rewrite it - all I really need is help figuring out how to get this to work in my filter: key ["Teaching Hospital Name"] != "" && item["Teaching Hospital Tax ID"] === ""

Comment: I updated the snipet. Basically if I understand it correctly, you have groups of keys and you want to return those which are empty if one of them are not empty

Comment: Although I have no idea what the code itself is doing, it works like a charm so thank you!

Comment: I will update my post to explain it better :)

Comment: updated the answer to explain better how it works

Answer (score 0):

Use `||` instead of `&&`:

```js
const obj = {
  'Manufacturer Name': 'Ascendis',
  'HCP First Name': 'John',
  'HCP Middle Name': '',
  'HCP Last Name': '',
  'HCP NPI': 2442,
  'HCP Credentials': '',
  'HCP State License Number': '',
  'HCP State of Licensure': '',
  'HCP Specialty': '',
  'Teaching Hospital Name': 'Trinity',
  'Teaching Hospital Tax ID': '',
  'Address 1': '',
  'Address 2': '',
  'Postal Code': '',
  'Spend Date': '',
  'Spend Currency': '',
  'Spend Amount': '',
  'Form of Payment': '',
  'Nature of Payment': '',
  'Home System Identifier': '',
  'Product Name': '',
  'Travel City': '',
  'Travel State': '',
  'Travel Country': ''
}

Object.entries(obj).forEach(([key, value]) => {
    if ((key === "Teaching Hospital Name" && value != "") || (key === "Teaching Hospital Tax ID" && value === "")) {
        delete obj[key]
    }
})

console.log(obj)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Array.prototype.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) to create a new object with the select properties removed:

```
Object.entries(obj).reduce((acc, [key, value]) => {
  if (
    (key === "Teaching Hospital Name" && value !== "") ||
    (key === "Teaching Hospital Tax ID" && value === "")
  ) {
    // do not add key/value to resulting object
    return { ...acc };
  }

  return { ...acc, [key]: value };
}, {});
```

This avoids mutating the original object.